# Why aren't my newts eagerly eating anymore?

Tags: aquarium, amphibians

I have two fire bellied newts. They have both recently left the water. When they had gills and spent most of their time in the water they fed well and daily.

Now they have left the water I find it difficult to get them to feed, I have to dangle their white worms in front of them for minutes, sometimes they don't eat at all.

Is this expected behaviour for newts that have just left the water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I purchased some vestigial fruit flies, which they happily pursue and consume.